# How to compare two MARIADB schemas via command line

Tags: mysql, mariadb, diff, mysqldbcompare

I tried some commands from (`https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-utilities-1.4-en/mysqldbcompare.html`)

But the comparison does not create tables and foreign keys...

What is the best command to compare two mariadb schemas creating columns, tables, procedures in order of creation to maintain schema integrity?

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you want to compare the schemas or merge them?

Comment: I want to compare tables, columns, not data. Example: i have a main database A in version 2.0, a database B in version 1.9. I want to get all diferences from A to B and set these differences like new tables, new colums in B. So A and B become in same version 2.0 .

Comment: In DBFORGE interface we call comparison. Yes it is a migration from different versions.

Comment: Consider using mysqldump with arguments to include stored routines but exclude data.  Then `diff` the two output files.

Comment: These commands does not include tables, only columns, they only show what is different but dont make any action about tables, foreign keys... Do you have some example how it works? thanks.